# Add content tag span in link_to in my helper function rails

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi guyz i want to add content_tag span in my existing function, and i don't know how to add in this function. Here is my helper function

```
 def taxons_tree_products_list_mobile(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
  return '' if max_level < 1 || root_taxon.children.empty?
  content_tag :ul, class: 'nav nav-pills nav-stacked' do
    root_taxon.children.map do |taxon|
      content_tag :li do
        link_to (taxon.name, seo_url(taxon)) +
        taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1)
      end
    end.join().html_safe
  end
end
```

And this helper function return **HTML** is something like that

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li><a href="/t/categories/bags">Bags</a></li>
  <li><a href="/t/categories/mugs">Mugs</a></li>
  <li><a href="/t/categories/clothing">Clothing</a></li>
</ul>
```

But i want **HTML** like that

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li><a href="/t/categories/bags"><span class="pull-right">(50)</span>Bags</a></li>
  <li><a href="/t/categories/mugs"><span class="pull-right">(50)</span>Mugs</a></li>
  <li><a href="/t/categories/clothing"><span class="pull-right">(50)</span>Clothing</a></li>
</ul>
```

So please someone help me that how I add this span in my Helper function. I appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  content_tag :li do
    concat link_to(seo_url(taxon)) do 
       content_tag(:span, '(50)', class: 'pull-right') + taxon.name
    end
    concat taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1)
  end
```

**UPDATE**: fixed the code. I don't know what `taxons_tree(...)` code returns, but for correct working it should be some string value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried this but it gives error 
syntax error, unexpected '+' ..... at here  "end +".

Comment: But when i remove this line "+
    taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1)" it gives correct html . so we are very near to the solution.

Comment: @QubaishBhatti Have you been able to fix the error?